# Converting string_view to null terminated c string

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

How would you convert a `std::string_view` to a null-terminated c string? I've passed a `string_view` into a function, and need to pass that into another function, which takes a `const char*` parameter. However, looking at [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data) for `string_view`, it says

> `data()` may return a pointer to a buffer that is not null-terminated. Therefore it is typically a mistake to pass `data()` to a routine that takes just a `const CharT*` and expects a null-terminated string.

Is there a way to properly get a null-terminated c string from a `string_view`?

Comment: This is what has prompted some people to make a separate `zstring_view` class. If the string view isn't referring to a null-terminated string, any method to create one is going to be expensive relatively.

Comment: `std::string s(view); f(s.c_str());`

Comment: You can try: string(stringViewObject).c_str()

Comment: should I just start off with taking a `const string&` parameter instead? If I'm going to be constructing a string anyways? I know I'll always be passing a `std::string` or string literal to this function

Comment: @Jeffmagma: "*Is there a way to properly get a null-terminated c string from a `string_view`?*" If the answer to this question was "yes", `string_view::substr` would not be able to return a `string_view`.